# How to send params in StackActions - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to pass params using `StackActions`. Page gets navigated successfully, but the params that have been sent is not received accordingly.

**MainScreen:**

```
reLogin = () => {
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: 'Login'
            },
            { 
                forceLogin: true <<-- This Flag Is Set Here
            }),
        ],
    }))
}
```

**LoginScreen:**

There is no error, but in `LoginScreen`'s `componentDidMount()`, below code always returns false.

```
componentDidMount() {
    alert(this.props.navigation.getParam('forceLogin', false))
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html), you need to pass the object of params like,

```
NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'Login',
        params : { forceLogin: true }
})
```